# How many unique selections can be made from x containers

Tags: combinatorics

Consider $x$ containers each containing $n$ objects. A **selection** is the set realised by drawing $1$ item from each container.

**How many *unique selections* can be made according to the specification?**

My initial reasoning:

Let the containers be $C_i ,  i = 1, 2, \cdots, x \,$, 
there are $\binom{n}{1} = n$ ways to  pick an item from $C_i$.

Let:

- $\mathbf{S}$ be the set of all **selections**,
- $\mathbf{s_i}$ denote a solution, and
- $\{a_j \in C_i : j = 1, \cdots, n\}$ be the $j^{th}$ element of $C_i$.

the number of **selections** in which $a_j$ appears is

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    number\, of \, occurrences\ of \ a_j &= 
    \begin{cases}
        n (x-1), &x>1 \\
        x
    \end{cases}\\
    & = \|\{a_j \in s_j \}: s_j \in \mathbf{s_i}\}\|
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Since $\|C_i\| = n$ and there are $x$ such sets, it follows that 
$\|\{a_j \in C_i : j = 1, \cdots, n\}\| = nx$.
Multiplying the number of elements in $\{a_j \in C_i : j = 1, \cdots, n\}$ with the number of times each one occurs in the set of all solutions yields:

$$
    \begin{cases}
        n^2 (x^2 - x), & x>1 \\
        nx^2
    \end{cases}\\
$$
But  this cannot be the size of the set of all solutions because just multiplying  (an empirical test with 3 containers and 2 objects show this is not $\|\mathbf{S}\|$).

I think since $\|C_i\| = n$, the correct approach is to multiply the number of occurrences of an object with the number of objects in one container.
$$
    \|\mathbf{S}\| = 
    \begin{cases}
        n^2 (x - 1), & x>1 \\
        nx
    \end{cases}\\
$$

My interpretation of this is as follows:

1. for a single container, the number of possible selections are $\mathbf{nx}$
2. for multiple containers, the number of possible selections are
   $\mathbf{n^2(x -1)}$

Comment: If each of the $x$ containers contains $n$ items and you are selecting one item from each container, then there are $n^x$ possible selections since there are $n$ choices at each of the $x$ selections.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks for that. I considered that as well but wasn't sure. I was thinking it might be expressed as the Cartesian product of the containers. My confusion started (and is still on going) when I used pythons `itertools.product`  to get the Cartesian product for 5 containers with 5 elements each returns $15625$ i.e. $5^6$. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: You should get $5^5 = 3125$.  Perhaps if you post your code, somebody could check it to see whether the code is correct.